# how to use javascript for string words comparision

Tags: javascript, diff

I am using two text areas. Project is about online typing test. I used two text area. First textarea contains the matter to be typed in second textarea. For calculating the the net typing speed I need a javascript diff algorithm.

[Javascript Diff Algorithm](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm) algo fits my all requirements..which uses this

[jsdiff.js](http://ejohn.org/files/jsdiff.js)

javascript file for differencing of two strings. and

[JS Diff Demo](http://blog.djsipe.com/js-diff/)

is a demo which uses the same javascript file...You should have look of this demo. But I how can I know count correct words typed? Trouble is that the javascript file provided is not using any comments nor gives any documentation.

Comment: If you're looking for something simple, it seems like you can just split on spaces/punctuation and count differences between the correct array and input array, which is what it seems like most online typing tests I take do.

Comment: @bbill thanx for suggestion but my requirement is exactly what i stated or you can see in the demo. I have done everything ok.. but I just want to count correct words typed by user. That would be a great help..

Comment: @bbill could you give me any link to a demo what you suggested. thanx in advance

Comment: Sure, I added an answer with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need much more explanation than the comment I placed above. I like the diff-highlighting your link shows, but if all you're after is counting the diffs, why does something like this not work? http://jsfiddle.net/vSySu/

```
var arr1 = $('#text1').val().split(' ');
var arr2 = $('#text2').val().split(' '); // split on whatever string or regex you want.

var diffs = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
        diffs++;
    }
}

alert(diffs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a [lenvenshtein algorithm](http://phpjs.org/functions/levenshtein/) to find the accuracy, and some basic string manipulation to count the words that are different. This can be improved but you get the idea:

```
function wordAccuracy(str1, str2) {

  var len = str1.length,
      distance = levenshtein(str1, str2),
      words1 = str1.split(' '),
      words2 = str2.split(' ');

  return {

    accuracy: 100 - (0|(distance * 100) / len) +'%',

    fail: words1.filter(function(word, idx){
      return word != words2[idx];
    }).length
  }
}

// Example:

var str1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';
var str2 = 'Lorme ipsmu dolor sit maet cnsectetur adipiscing elot';

console.log(wordAccuracy(str1, str2));
//^ {
//    accuracy: '86%'
//    fail: 5
//  }
```