# How to compare two string, find the difference return the missing words with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

```
let main = "i am really calm at this moment";
let sub = "am this";

function missingWords () {
  
  let mainArr = main.split(" ");
  let subArr = sub.split(" ");


 return mainArr.toLowerCase().filter( x => !subArr.toLowerCase.includes(x));
};
  
console.log(missingWords());
```

Comment: Hi. Does these help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480351/how-to-use-javascript-for-string-words-comparision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050932/detect-differences-between-two-strings-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have a `toLowerCase()` function. If you want to make all elements in the array lowercase, you should first convert the string to lowercase, then split by a space.

```js
let main = "i am really calm at this moment";
let sub = "am this";

function missingWords() {

  let mainArr = main.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let subArr = sub.toLowerCase().split(" ");


  return mainArr.filter(x => !subArr.includes(x));
};

console.log(missingWords());
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason to split both of strings.
You can use 'includes' also on string and not only on array.

```
function missingWords(mainString,subString) {

  const lowerMainString = mainString.toLowerCase();
  const lowerSubString = subString.toLowerCase();

  return lowerMainString.split(" ").filter(x => !lowerSubString.includes(x));
};

missingWords("i am really calm at this moment", "am this");
```